# Can we burninate [hardware-recommendation]?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed, tags, scope

The [help center](https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic) says:

> #### Questions that you should avoid:
>
> - Linux Mint, Elementary OS, Backtrack, Gnome-Remix (prior to 13.04), budgie-remix (16.04 and 16.10) and other Linux distributions (try our friends at Unix & Linux Stack Exchange).
> - Bug reports (How do I submit a bug?).
> - Issues with the next version of Ubuntu (Ubuntu+1) (More information about Alpha and Beta release issues).
> - **Shopping or Hardware Recommendations**
> - Support for versions for Ubuntu releases past their Support or "End of Life" (EOL) — unless the question is asking how to upgrade to a supported release.

We have a close reason for each of the above, except for "Shopping or Hardware Recommendations.

If these questions are considered off-topic (in my experience they get closed as off-topic with a custom reason or as duplicates of [Where can I find a list of computers guaranteed to work with Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/131/which-computers-are-guaranteed-to-work) or similar) then shouldn't we

- get rid of the [hardware-recommendation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/hardware-recommendation) tag so visitors hopefully don't waste time making nice well-formatted posts like [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/879810/recomendation-of-ultra-portable-laptop-dual-boot-ubuntu-windows) which will be closed
- <strike>consider making a close reason, maybe with a link to the question that these posts are normally closed as dupe of?</strike>

Comment: I'm all for burninating it, but I think the "primarily opinion based" close reason might serve for this sort of thing.

Comment: @terdon hmm yes that makes sense

Comment: Ah, also, note that there is a limit to the custom close reasons we already have and we're already at it. So, to create a new custom close reason, we'd have to remove one of the existing ones.

Comment: We already even had to ask SE for more to get where we are.. and they didn't particularly like it.

Comment: I'm all for burnination of the tag as well.

Comment: On the one hand, if an asker self-tags 'hardware recommendation', it makes it easy to track down and close the question. :-/ Now that I checked, there are ~183 questions currently under that tag that may/may-not-be on topic.

Comment: @KevinBowen true that it makes it easier to find off-topic posts, but I don't think we should have a tag just for that purpose?

Comment: @Seth I apologise for thoughtlessly creating stress and completely retract my foolish second suggestion

Comment: @Zanna nothing wrong with the suggestion, I just added that for posterity :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This seems to be a pretty clear cut case.  I'll put in a request for it to be blacklisted and/or burninated.

Comment: Wow thanks! I will have a look at the questions too.

Comment: Done. If it comes back, lemme know and I'll blacklist.